# Using mosquitto native acl file along with an auth plug-in

Tags: authentication, authorization, acl, mqtt, mosquitto

I have written an authentication module for mosquitto using the plug-in system. Now once the plug-in is set from the configurations I suppose it calls the `mosquitto_auth_acl_check` for acl authorization.

If I am to use inbuilt **acl_file** option along with the **auth_plugin** option(just for connect authentication), would it be possible?

Or am I supposed to implement the whole thing in my plug-in itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current versions of mosquitto - 1.4.x and earlier - only allow the built in authentication and access control OR a plugin to be used at once. That means that what you want isn't possible.

Version 1.5 will allow multiple plugins, including the built in support.

Comment: Do you have a 1.5 release lined up in recent future?